# SQL: Select exactly two rows with a matching ID based on two given values

Tags: mysql, sql

What I need seems kind of complicated, but then again I'm not that good at SQL. Basically I have a table that stores conversation participants. I need a query that will, using two provided User IDs, determine if a conversation exists containing ONLY the two given users. Conversations containing additional users beyond just these two shouldn't be counted---only a single 1-on-1 conversation between the two given users.

Here is my SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/284e1/33/0

And my in-progress query which isn't doing the trick:

`SELECT * 
FROM mybb_conversation_participants
WHERE conversation_id IN (
    SELECT conversation_id
    FROM mybb_conversation_participants
    WHERE (user_id = 6 OR user_id = 11)
    GROUP BY conversation_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
);`

I don't think I'm understanding the `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` part, because this query returns all conversations containing the two users, even if other users exist in that conversation as well. Again, only 1-on-1 conversations between the two provided users should be selected, otherwise the query should select nothing. For example, in the SQLfiddle above, only rows with a `conversation_id` of `12` or `19` should've returned, since all the other matches include more than two rows.

That is what I was hoping the `HAVING` statement would do, but apparently not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT conversation_id 
FROM mybb_conversation_participants
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING SUM( (user_id NOT IN (6, 11) ) = 0;
```

What is this doing?  It is aggregating by the conversation id.  Then, for each conversation it counts the number of times a user is *not* one of the two.  It accepts conversations where this is true.

If you prefer positivity, this might be easier to follow:

```
HAVING SUM( (user_id IN (6, 11)) = COUNT(*)
```

That is saying that all the users on the conversation are accounted for with the ones you have chosen.

Finally, if you want to be sure that both (all) are involved:

```
HAVING SUM( (user_id IN (6, 11)) = COUNT(*) AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2
```

Comment: Sorry, I commented before I saw your edits. This is perfect, thanks so much for the quick response!

Comment: been looking at it for hours and just don't get it